# How to handle scroll in NestedScrollView

Tags: android, scroll, nestedscrollview

What I want to do is to handle the scroll NestedScrollView.
But when I "setOnScrollChangedListener" to it, and then I scroll the view, nothing happens, the method "setOnScrollChangedListener" even isn't be called...
Who could tell me why? And when will the method "setOnScrollChangedListener" be called?

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/MyAppbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:background="@color/material_deep_teal_500"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bgheader"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:background="@drawable/example"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="24dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/error_color"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:text="This text is part of first Cardview\n\n"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textColor="@color/abc_search_url_text"
                        android:text="This text is part of second Cardview\n\n"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In MainActivity, I want to listen to the scroll. I did like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private NestedScrollView nestedScrollView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        nestedScrollView = (NestedScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll);
        nestedScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
                System.out.println("I am scrolling the view...");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: post your code please

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same code without

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

in the NestedScrollView and it worked for me. Give it a try

Comment: It didn't work for me. I don't know why...After I a delete this code, the layout is broken.

Comment: @黄圣蕾 I don't really know how the `CoordinatorLayour` works, but you may try a `RelativeLayout` instead.